# If $ay''y+bx''x=ay'y+bx'x$ then can we write $y''=y' x''=x'$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $2\cos x+3 \sin x=(2l-3m)\sin x +(2m+3l) \cos x$
then, $2=2m+3l$
and $3=2l-3m$

but if, $ay''y+bx''x=ay'y+bx'x$
then can we write, $y''=y'$,
$x''=x'$ ?
thnx 2 answer,

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you first line holds is that the functions $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ are linearly independent. If you have a linear combination of linearly independent functions then you can equate coefficients, as in the case given.

In general though, you cannot just equate coefficients. For a simple counter-example, take $x=y$, $a=b$, $x'=y''$ and $y'=x''$ (eg. $1\times 2\times 3+1\times 5 \times 3=1\times 5\times 3+1\times 2\times 3$, but $2 \neq 5$).